# How to print output from tcpdump using Java Process class

Tags: java, linux, process, tcpdump

I would like to read and process the output of tcpdump line by line as connections come in. So far I am using the Process class.  I also want to run as a non-root user, so I have configured sudo:
user1 ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/sudo

I am running on RHEL 6.4.

My Java code looks like this:

```
    String[] tcpdumpCmd = {"/usr/bin/sudo", "-n", "/usr/sbin/tcpdump", "-i", "eth0", "port 8561"};
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(tcpdumpCmd).start();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    tcpdumpOut = null;
    tcpdumpLineCnt = 0;
    while ((tcpdumpOut = in.readLine()) != null ) {
        System.out.println(tcpdumpOut);
        tcpdumpLineCnt++;
    }

    System.out.println("Output lines: " + tcpdumpLineCnt+"\nCommand exit code: " + p.exitValue());
```

The command works fine, so it is obvious to me what is happening because when I Ctrl-C I get the output printed.  So it doing a sort of "buffering" until I interrupt it (at which point the remaining code isn't executed, so I don't get to the RC part.)

I assume that either my problem is in how I handle the output in my while loop, or it just cannot be done in this way.  So I kindly ask if anyone has any advice for me.

Comment: `ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/sudo` wee! You could have _at least_ restricted that to the tcpdump command :p

Comment: +1 for using `ProcessBuilder` by the way. People still using `Runtime.exec()` are too many.

Comment: What's the problem, `tcpdump` buffering its output? Use the `-l` switch to make it line-buffered.

Comment: Thanks fge.  That was a typo:  ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/tcpdump.  I cannot even imagine what NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/sudo would do.  :-)

Comment: Well, I just wasted 3 hours of my life figuring out that:
command = {"/usr/sbin/tcpdump", "-i", "eth0"}
works but:
command = {"/usr/sbin/tcpdump", "-i eth0"}

Fails, but I've not figured out how to catch any error at all.  Perhaps I should do a bit of rtfm:ing...